# Помогите разобраться с Битами и Мегабитами memory_limit на сервере

Tags: php, веб-сервер

Добрый день, столкнулся с ошибкой на сайте

```
[Mon Nov 13 10:53:10 2017] [error] [client ........] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 82 bytes) in
```

как я понял на сервере для обработки скрипта не хватает memory_limit  , сейчас выделено памяти на сервере memory_limit  1024M
помогите понять, что такое M (1024M) это мегабиты или мебибайты или как понять сколько не хватает памяти для обработки скриптов ?

Comment: сейчас у вас скрипт использовал 1 ГигаБайт. Я бы предложил пересмотреть логику скрипта, что бы он такие объемы не использовал

Comment: т.е я правильно понимаю что скрипт превышает обоьем выделенной памяти ?

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете, он сожрал целый гиг, который и был максимально выделен

Comment: спасибо за инфо